Best Mini Split BTU Size for Hot Miami Garage: 12'W x 28'D x 12'H
EDIT FOR CONFUSION: The condensor unit will be outside near my front entrance.
I'm a photographer with 12'W x 28'D x 12'H Garage as my studio. It gets very hot, so I've decided to get a Mini Split installed. The outdoor condensor unit would be installed outside near my entrance on a 3 ft wide wall (HOA won't allow it outside the garage). This would be about 30' to 40' away from the indoor ceiling evaporator unit. Is that distance ok? Would love recommendations on the BTU size and/or Mini-Split model you would suggest. Hopefully there would be no issues with electricity/tripping breakers. Thanks so much!

it must be outside, try asking for roof mount

If you own the place rather than rent, see if you can get on the Board of the HOA and get the rule changed. For anything beyond a traditional window unit (which would be inefficient and not nearly big enough) you really need to have part of the system outside.

I'm very sorry for the confusion! The outdoor condensor would be outside next to the entrance. I was just saying it couldn't be outside the garage, so the distance would be far.

It's very difficult to guess correct size unless you know the root causes of the heat. If you're thinking it's ambient temperature, no. It's solar gain.  Sunbeams bring 300 BTU per square foot, and roof colors other than white absorbing almost all of it.  So how much sunlight the structure gets hit with (vs tree shade etc.) is the #1 influencer.  "Square footage" is useless.

The condenser must be mounted outside.
Communicate with the manufacturer of the unit as to the length of the lines.  There may be a need to have freon added to make up for the extra length.   This may be done from the factory if they can provide a precharged unit.  If not you will need an AC tech to add the needed freon.
Sizing depends on many factors along with size of the room. Use a sizing guide.  when the size is determined, then you will also know the Amperage requirement.

Thanks. This sizing guide is based on floor sq ft, but I am I still ok to use these estimates with high ceilings? I don't care about the taller areas getting cool, but the unit itself would be about 12 ft high.

@NewHomeGuy,  scroll down the page and there is info on adjusting size for higher ceilings.

Ahh, perfect. I need to add 80% (20% for height / 30% for insulation / 30% for climate).

The tech and service personal are very good as well.   The units come pre charged.  I have them in 3 rental properties and they work very well.
